# POST method is ajax gives 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

This is my ajax

```
$('#saveButton').click(function(){
    alert('savebutton');
    $.ajax({
        url: projectUrl+"updateDoctor", 
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (res) {
            formdata = new FormData();
                    //self.doctor(new Doctor());
                }

        });

});
```

and this is requestmapping

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("updateDoctor")

    public String updateDoctor(@RequestParam("doctormetada") String doctormetada,@RequestParam(value="image",required=false) MultipartFile image)
    {

        Doctor doctor=doctorServiceImpl.updateDoctor(doctormetada,image);
        return doctor.getId().toString();

    }
```

and this is my save button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="saveButton"
                                                    >
                                                    <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Save
                                                </button>
```

when I am hitting the save button then I am getting the following error in browser console

```
POST http://localhost:8080/Mo/updateDoctor 400 (Bad Request)
```

Can any body please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest looking at the spring mvc log (it's usually in INFO/WARN) and look for clues.
Attaching the application context and the log will give us some additional information to help you.

Comment: @Haim Thanks for your suggestion but can you please tell me where would I get the spring MVC log.Is it defined manually or its inbulit in STS

Comment: If you are using log4j 
Place a file named log4j.properties in the classpath.
The following should create a log (probably under your server bin directory)
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=app.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

Comment: I think you need to change
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, R,stdout
uncomment 
#log4j.appender.R.File=${logfile}/application.log
Change 
log4j.appender.R.File= application.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in your Service is throwing an exception causing your controller to return a HTTP 400. Check that you are passing all the required data to your service layer in your doctormetada.

Check your application logs to see specifically where you are getting the exception thrown from.

Comment: Thanks for answering,I did your way.Its showing the same error

Comment: Can you post your entire controller code. Did you enable your log4j logging? what did that show?